# Moving gameobject with animation according to my script Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity, animation, gameobject

I am developing a game with Unity3D with an horizontal list of elements which you can move with arrows. Here you can see an example:

[image: example]

I have created animations in order to modify the alpha value of the elements and to move them according to my script:

```
void Update () {
    if (managePositionInUpdate) {
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Screen.width * positionX, Screen.height * positionY, 10));
    }
}
```

In my animation, the alpha value of the centered element is initially 1 and after the animation the alpha value is 0.5, this works correctly; however, in this animation I have also put positionX of my script initially with a value A, and after the animation with a value B, and this doesn't work correctly.

I have tested the code and it works correctly without animation, but I can't get it works according to my animation. What can I do? I have read about apply root motion but It also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you setting the flag properly? Tried debugging the value of the position?

Comment: @2600th What flag do you refer?

Comment: managePositionInUpdate

Comment: Yes, it is. I think it is not possible to modify the value of the script from animator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/194798/scripting-animated-variables.html

> Animations always "take over" the control of the animated value
>   (position / rotation / or a script value) because it always sets the
>   value to an absolute value. However you still can affect the value but
>   you have to decide what's the better solution in your case:
>
> Use [LateUpdate()][1] to modify the value. Modify means you just scale
>   the actual value instead of setting it to a new value. In LateUpdate
>   all animation components have applied their values for thi frame and
>   you can "overwrite" the value as you need it.